# How to replace a task on Google App Engine Task Queue?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue

When adding a certain task to the task queue, I would like to make sure there is only one such task. If this task already exists, I would like to delete it and add the new task instead (postponing its execution is ok also). This is my code:

```
queue = taskqueue.Queue()
queue.delete_tasks_by_name('task_name')
task = taskqueue.Task(
    name = 'task_name',
    url = '/task/url',
    method = 'GET',
    countdown = 3600)
queue.add(task)
```

When running the code it raises a `TombstonedTaskError`, which make sense according to the docs. Is there a way to replace or postpone execution of an existing task?

Comment: @marcadian that's exactly what the code in the question does..

Comment: yup, missed that. Why do you need to replace the task? From your example, there is no payload / params changed.

Comment: @marcadian I need to restart the countdown

Comment: Probably you do not need taskqueue here, put an entry in datastore, and have a cron job run says every 5 mins. If entry.t < current_time, execute it

Answer (score 0):

[Use tags instead of names](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-pull#Python_Adding_tasks_to_a_pull_queue). Give the tag a unique name then do a [lease_task_by_tag](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/queues#Queue_lease_tasks_by_tag) to see if it exists.

add(taskqueue.Task(payload='parse1', method='PULL', tag='parse'))
lease_tasks_by_tag(lease_seconds, max_tasks, tag=None, deadline=10)

Comment: Thanks but `lease_tasks_by_tag` applies only to pull queue tasks. My task are push queue tasks.